# Shopify Metafield List of Collections

Tags: shopify, liquid, liquid-template, shopify-liquid

I need to get the list of images from my metafield(content type: collection list) in collection. I'm using this logic but it is not working...

Code snippet

```
{% assign top_collections = collection.metafields.custom.c-top-collections %}
{% if top_collections %}
  <ul>
    {% for collection in top_collections %}
      <li>{{ collection.value }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
  </ul>
{% endif %}
```

Please, what is the correct form of doing this? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

To get your array you need to write this `{{ collection.metafields.custom.c-top-collections.value }}`

Comment: Were you meaning this?
`{% assign top_collections = collection.metafields.custom.c-top-collections %}
{% if top_collections %}
  <ul>
    {% for collection in top_collections %}
      <li>{{ collection.metafields.custom.c-top-collections.value }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
  </ul>
{% endif %}`

Comment: I mean this :):
{% assign top_collections = collection.metafields.custom.c-top-collections.value %}

Answer (score 0):

Example solution here with some variables being pulled:

```
{% assign collection-list = collection.metafields.menu.c-top-collections %}

{% for collection-list-item in collection-list.value -%}
 {% if collection-list != blank %}
  <img class="rounded-full h-28 w-28 object-cover object-center aspect-square   " src="{{ collection-list-item | image_url }}" alt="{{ collection-list-item.image.alt }}"/>
  <h2 class="text-xl mt-4 text-center">{{ collection-list-item.title }}</h2>
 {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Since you've added an example, it adds to the existing answer. You could have appended your answer to the exisiting answer.